# Image Compression Rate in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to save a bulk of image files after cropping them with `cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9`, but this is extremely slow. It takes about one hour for 5000 images.

```
    cv2.imwrite(fn, img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION),9)
```

This is the command along with the path(`fn`), the image(`img`) and the compression mode, 9. If I use the default mode 3, that is by not giving the third argument the png's size gets doubled.

My qusetion is, Is there a way to optimize the process of compression, or any other library that can do this given that `img` has been opened using `img = cv2.imread(src)`.

Comment: The optimum compression to use for a PNG depends on the content of the image. In these days of low-cost, high performance storage, it seems not that worthwhile spending hours compressing stuff - what size both in pixels and bytes are your images? Have you considered multi-processing which is the obvious way to go in these days of multi-core CPUs?

Comment: The images vary from 30 kb to 1.5 mb. The content is scanned documents. Pixels are also varying from 30*45 to 4000*6000. The data is very variable. I haven't tried multi-processing.